# Jquery cycle - wrap images in div tags without breaking thumbnail pagers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cycle, pager

I'm using the jquery cycle plug in and am wrapping each image in a div tag to centre each slide, all of which are different widths:

```
<div><img src="img1.jpg" width="522" height="347"  alt=""/></div>
<div><img src="img2.jpg" width="420" height="347"  alt=""/></div>
<div><img src="img3.jpg" width="231" height="347"  alt=""/></div>
```

This works fine but it breaks the pagerAnchorBuilder script.

From this page: [Jquery cycle - How can I wrap my images in span tags without breaking the thumbnail pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647378/jquery-cycle-how-can-i-wrap-my-images-in-span-tags-without-breaking-the-thumbn) , I've got this:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {

    var src = $("img", slide).attr("rel");

        return '<a href="#"><img src="' + src + '" width="60" height="40" style="position:absolute; top:540px;"/></a></li>';
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I'm sure I don't need to point out I am pretty new to javascript! I'd be grateful for any tips!

The page in question is here: http://wildwood-design.org/twagons.html

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Can you give a link to your page, or a fiddle?

Comment: Why don't you have a parent element to all the images, and just use text-align: center; on that?

Comment: I've updated my post with a link to the page in question. A bit embarrassed about the million other mistakes I probably made!

Comment: I don't think text-align will work as I think the javascript is dynamically creating the top and left properties or something. I should try it though.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found the answer for anyone who happens on this thread (hopefully not me in 6 months time). Replace the return line in the function above with:

```
return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src') + '" width="60" height="40" style="position:absolute; top:540px;"/></a></li>';
```